# Not using VirtualBox as NetworkInterface in Multicast Java?

Tags: java, networking, multicast

I have an issue while working with Multicast in java. I'm trying to test the Multicast using a simple Sender-Receiver program which should work on Windows over two computers in the same subnet (see the code after). The problem is that it use one of my VirtualBox interface as the `NetworkInterface` and not my wireless card' one, making it impossible to send datas over two computers (I tried). If I set manually the Interface to use (see the comments in my code) it works perfectly over two computer in the same subnet (which is my goal).
My question is: is there any workaround to not select the VirtualBox interface by default, or to iterate over all interfaces (knowing that the VB ones have exactly the same properties as my wireless card... even `isVirtual` return `false`)?

Here is the sender:

```
public class MulticastSender extends Thread {

    final static String INET_ADDR = "239.192.0.1";

    MulticastSocket serverSocket;

    public void run() {
        // Get the address that we are going to connect to.
        InetAddress addr = null;
        try {
            addr = InetAddress.getByName(INET_ADDR);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Open a new MulticastSocket, which will be used to send the data.
        try {
            serverSocket = new MulticastSocket();

            // if I set it manually it works (here goes the IP of my PC n°1)
            //serverSocket.setInterface(InetAddress.getByName("IP of my first PC"));

            serverSocket.joinGroup(addr);

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                String msg = "Sent message no " + i;

                // Create a packet that will contain the data
                // (in the form of bytes) and send it.
                DatagramPacket msgPacket = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(),
                        msg.getBytes().length, addr, 8080);
                serverSocket.send(msgPacket);

                System.out.println("Server sent packet with msg: " + msg);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Receiver:

```
public class MulticastReceiver implements Runnable {

    final static String INET_ADDR = "239.192.0.1";

    public void run() {
        // Get the address that we are going to connect to.
        InetAddress address = null;
        try {
            address = InetAddress.getByName(INET_ADDR);
            MulticastSocket clientSocket = new MulticastSocket(8080);

            // if I set it manually it works (here goes the IP of my PC n°2)
            //clientSocket.setInterface(InetAddress.getByName("IP of my second PC"));

            // Create a buffer of bytes, which will be used to store
            // the incoming bytes containing the information from the server.
            // Since the message is small here, 256 bytes should be enough.
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];

            //Join the Multicast group.
            clientSocket.joinGroup(address);

            while (true) {
                // Receive the information and print it.
                DatagramPacket msgPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                clientSocket.receive(msgPacket);
                String msg = new String(buf, 0, buf.length);
                System.out.println("Received msg: " + msg);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```